# How to append all DIV starts with class and repeat this proc again?

Tags: jquery

Let me explain it direct in code:

I have:

```
<dl class="ctx accordion">
   <dt>headline<a>x</a></dt>
   <dd><!----></dd>
</dl>
<p class="ctx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
<p class="ctx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
<p class="ctx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>

<dl class="ctx accordion">
   <dt>headline<a>x</a></dt>
   <dd><!----></dd>
</dl>
<p class="ctx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>

<dl class="ctx accordion">
   <dt>headline<a>x</a></dt>
   <dd><!----></dd>
</dl>
<p class="ctx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
<p class="ctx">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
```

And i want to accomblish that all .ctx:not('.accordion') go into the prev .accordion dd and so on

Here is my try:

```
     $('.accordion').each(function(index) {

     var nextCTX = $(this).nextAll('.ctx').not('.accordion');
     $(this).find('dd').append(nextCTX);
 });
```

But it dont work well. In this example i catch everything with .ctx and put it into the first .accordion dd

whats wrong?

#

EDIT

i need a solution to stop the accordion loop.
my current looks like:
     $('.accordion dd').append(function() {
         return $(this).closest('.accordion').nextUntil('.accordion').filter('.ctx:not(".stopLast")');
     });

in this case the loop cant stop an include everything after a elem with .stopLast

Comment: Do you want to append all <p> in <dl> accordion?

Comment: You are mixing `nextCTX` and `nextCMP`.

Comment: sry, fixes it, c&p mistake, and yes i want to get all p into the prev accordion

Answer (score 2):

Target the elements that you wish to append to, and then find all elements that match `p.ctx` until the next `.accordion`

element :

```
$('.accordion dd').append(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.accordion').nextUntil('.accordion').filter('p.ctx');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BHy69/)

Comment: ok, how can i stop with this kind of version the append process? in example i realize that no html contains the css class .stoPLast are inside the append loop. but the problem is that every div contains the .ctx class go inside the accordion. that i want to stop

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.accordion').filter(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.accordion').filter('.ctx').appendTo($(this).find('dd'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjPWV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$('.accordion').each(function (index) {
    var nextCTX = $(this).nextUntil('.accordion').filter('.ctx');
    $(this).find('dd').append(nextCMP);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the .accordion elements will always be siblings of .ctx:not('.accordion'), then you can use:

```
$('.ctx.accordion').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $elemsToMove = $this.nextUntil('.accordian', '.ctx');

    $this.find('dd').append($elemsToMove);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/phDdz/